# How to create responsive modal box for responsive websites?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I want to create modal box which would adjust according to device height and device width. Initially i tried Bootstrap dialog box, But my problem is whenever content exceeds device height i am not able to show the entire content of modal box.(especially in small screen mobile device)So i even tried adding wrapper for content inside modal byusing iscroll, it works great but if i add iscroll, pages of website wont scroll in mobile devices. I am struck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: quick google search returns this: http://cameronbaney.com/2012/07/26/pure-html5css3-responsive-modal-window/ do you have some example code codepen etc etc.

Comment: Can we see what you have coded so far?

Comment: @TheCellarRoom: Yes.. That definitely works as a modal. But once the content inside a modal exceeds more than mobile screen height we cant scroll it.

Comment: @TheCellarRoom,@MGDTech: Here is my code. Sorry if the code is too messy. First time i am using code pen and i am still learning web development, sorry if i have provided insufficient data.here is the link:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvBpE Thank you